# A different ObjectWriter for each POJO to be serialized?

Tags: java, jackson2

The code that [quicktype.io](http://quicktype.io) generates makes a separate `ObjectReader` and `ObjectWriter` for each POJO that has to be [de]serialized.

Is this a good practice (performance-wise) vs. using a single `ObjectMapper` for every class in a project (which is what I am currently doing) or does it not make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

[quicktype](https://quicktype.io?l=java) now only generates a single `ObjectReader` and `ObjectWriter`. We were told that this was the guidance of the Jackson documentation.